# Reading a FileStream from an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I retrieving a document from SharePoint 2010 using the Client OM. I'm able to retrieve the document using

```
var spFileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(<SPContext>, <documentPath>);
```

This return a type ConnectStream. I'm then transferring the ConnectStream into a FileStream like so:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(<documentName> + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
       spFileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fs);
  }
```

This does write a physical file to the local file system, but I'm hoping to avoid this in the future. Now I have a FileStream of a PDF document in my codebehind. I also have a UserControl to display PDF in the aspx page. From the codebehind the UserControl accepts the file path like so:

```
<userControlName>.FilePath = <url>;
```

Is there a way to link the fs object to the file path for the UserControl?

Please let me know if more detail is needed,Thanks.

Comment: Be glad to help but please provide some more details (and code) so that I (or anyone) can get more context about what you're trying to do.  File Stream is not the same thing as a File object so need to see more code to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass stream object then you have to create a public property of `Stream` type in UserControl.

Define the property in `UserControl`,

```
public System.IO.Stream InputStream {get;set;}
```

and assign the reference of stream object from within the code-behind of host (.aspx or .ascx) of UserControl.

```
UserControl1.InputStream=stream;
```